# Redirect NET CORE HttpResponse to application root

Tags: redirect, root, asp.net-core-3.1

I am working with Razor Pages, NET CORE 3, I implemented followings in order to catch and handle 404 errors:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(context =>
{
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

    if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        response.Redirect("./NotFound", false);
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
});
```

Here it works:
`http://myServer/myApp/nonExistingPage` -> `http://myServer/myApp/NotFound`

In this case obviously it does not work:
`http://myServer/myApp/doesNotExists/nonExistingPage` -> `http://myServer/myApp/doesNotExists/NotFound`

I read that the redirect should be `response.Redirect("~/NotFound", false);`. With this I get:

`http://myServer/myApp/nonExistingPage` -> `http://myServer/NotFound`
`http://myServer/myApp/doesNotExists/nonExistingPage` -> `http://myServer/NotFound`

Am I missing something or what?

Answer (score 0):

`./` means the current directory. To access `NotFound` with such url, this file need to be created in the current directory. `~/` means the web root path `wwwroot/`. You can try to modify it in this way.

```
response.Redirect("/NotFound", false);
```

It will not be affected by the directory.

Edit:

You can create a file `NotFound.html` in the `wwwroot` directory. Redirect to this page when a 404 occurs. And the parameter need to be modified.

```
 response.Redirect("https://localhost:44344/NotFound.html", false);
```

Or create this file in a folder of the server, and then redirect to it in current project.

Comment: In which directory is NotFound.cshtml placed?

Comment: All my pages are in {ProjectFolder}/pages. But I am getting crazy with this stuff, since locally where the app is running on localhost/ everything is working fine. If I deploy it on myServer/myApp/ many `PageModel`::Redirections make troubles

Comment: I have edit this answer, please check if it can meet the demand.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I don't think it is a clean solution. What if I had more applications with different NotFound pages? I found a workaround, also not really nice, but I think I can live with. I will post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

After a long research I have not been able to find a proper way to handle it.
As a workaround I came out with the following solution:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(context =>
{
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

    if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        if (request.Path.HasValue && request.Path.Value.EndsWith("/NotFound"))
        {
            response.Redirect("../NotFound");
        }
        else
        {
            response.Redirect("./NotFound");
        }
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
});
```

First it is redirected to `./NotFound`. If the redirected page does not exists either, it means we are not at the root of the project, so it is catched again and redirected to `../NotFound` wich means a level less, and so on until it is found (at root).

If somebody has a better/nicer solution, you are welcome to post it.